Как строится слова в совершенном и несовершенном виде?
Например: получить и получать, что мы должны знать, чтобы определить совершенный или несовершенный вид в данном примере? По суффиксу?
Другой пример из обучающего материала: везде пишут читать и прочитать, здесь приставка про- указывается как один из вариантов? Может же наверное быть и такие варианты для св и нсв: ЗАчитать, ПЕРЕчитать, Считать, Вчитать и другие?

Все способы образования видовых пар  https://studfile.net/preview/5765938/page:6/

Носитель языка в целом способен интуитивно разграничивать виды глагола. По видам, по аспектуальности глагола есть куча морфологических теорий.
В практической плоскости учение о разграничении вида строится на понятии незаконченности и законченности действия и, соответственно, на особых вопросах, задаваемых к несовершенному и совершенному видам.
Для совершенного вида вопросом будет что cделать? Ответ: получить. То есть осуществить, закончить действие, довести до конца. Применительно ко понятию времени данное действие либо закончено до момента речи (я - что сделал, что осуществил? - получил), либо будет полностью, от начала до конца, осуществлено в будущем, после момента речи (я - что сделаю? что осуществлю? - получу).
Для несовершенного вида вопросом будет что делать?. Ответ: получать. То есть брать, принимать, но это действие как бы продолжается, идёт, но не имеет конца, не имеет начала и финиша. Поэтому во всех временах это продолжающееся действие, но не финализированное. Действие либо шло (не завершилось, а шло) до момента речи (я - что делал? - получал), либо идёт сейчас, в момент речи, (я - что делаю? - получаю), либо будет идти (не осуществится, а будет просто проявляться, наличествовать) после момента речи, то есть в будущем (я - что буду делать? - буду получать).
Это я не касаюсь непрямых употреблений времён вроде настоящего времени в значении будущего и т.д.
Кстати, вот механизм разграничения для вас: у совершенного вида нет форм с будет. Нельзя сказать, я буду получить. Раз так, то глагол получить однозначно совершенного вида.
Кроме того у совершенного вида нет настоящего времени. Вы можете быстро и не думая сказать я получал, я получаю, я буду получать (три формы, три!) и так же быстро произнести я получил, я получу (формы только две, формы  будет нет). Иными словами, где три времени - там несовершенный вид, где два - там совершенный.
Далее, в видовых парах, в которых у одного глагола суффикс и-ть, а у другого а-ть, совершенным видом является глагол на и-ть.
Решить (св.) - решать (нсв.); разрешить (св.) - разрешать (нсв.); охмурить (св.) - охмурять (нсв.); родить (св.) - рожать (нсв.); обложить (св.) - облагать (нсв.).
Тут можно по суффиксу определять.
Есть и самый деревянный путь определения: установите словарь на смартфон и каждые две минуты в него заглядывайте, глаголы в словарях имеют пометы по виду, так что можете просто запоминать, у какого глагола какой вид. Ха-ха-ха!

Что до приставок, то нужно разграничивать чисто грамматические и словообразовательные приставки. Первые меняю только вид, а вторые образую новое слово.
В паре читать - прочитать приставка про- ничего не добавляет к лексической семантике слова, к его смыслу, а лишь меняет грамматическое значение слова, образую совершенный вид, обычно понимаемый как "законченное" действие. Поэтому про- в данном случае - это грамматическая приставка.
Приведённые вами другие приставки, помимо добавления значения совершенного вида, добавляют в производящее слово новое значение, новый смысл, семантически (по смыслу) осложняют производящее слово. Поэтому эти приставки словообразовательные.
Например, приставка пере- добавляет значение повторного действия, значение совершения действия заново. То есть читать - это просто читать, а перечитать - это прочитать ещё раз, заново. Также у пере- есть значения охвата множества предметов, например я перечитал все книги, то есть прочитал всё. Выходит, читать и прочитать - это одно и тоже, продолжающееся и законченное, а читать и перечитать, извините, разные слова, да, однокоренные, но разные, поскольку приставка пере- изменила значение слова.
Глагол считать вообще на синхронном уровне уже неродственен читать из-за расхождения значений и имеет современный корень счит-. Короче, это вообще разные слова с разными корнями. У читать это -чит-, а у считать -счит-.
Вчитать вообще фиксируется только у Даля в значении "зачитать, зачислять, вчислять, засчитывать". Тоже близости с читать вроде как не особо много.
Зачитать тоже по значению отличается от читать, хотя в зачитать в значении "продекламировать кому-то, продекламировать вслух" трудно выделить значение префикса за-, поскольку не приходят что-то на ум глаголы, в которых их приставка за- совпадала бы по значения с за- в зачитать.
Для того чтобы сводить слова в видовую пару, в видовые корреляты, требуется лишь грамматическая, лишь видовая (незаконченность или продолжение --- законченность) разница в значениях слов. Писать и написать - вот несовершенный и совершенный вид,  но не дописать, потому что дописать - это писать до конца, а в отдельном глаголе писать никакого до конца нет.
Это главное: видовая приставка меняет грамматическое значение слова, а словообразовательная приставка меняет и грамматическое, и лексическое его значения.
